# Temporary copy exists in memory after multibyte to wide char conversion

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode, secure-coding

I am trying to convert a secure char string to unicode string. Since I need to handle secure data I ensurd to clear the memory after its usage. 
I tried following the APIs to unicode conversion.

- `MultiByteToWideChar()`
- `A2W()`
- `mbstowcs_s()`

Conversion to Unicode string worked successfully with above all APIs.
I have cleared all the secured data memory after the above operation, including the o/p unicode value.
But while dumping the memory after this, a copy of the unicode string remains in memory. I have ensured that all my variables handling the secure data is cleared( by using `SecureZeroMemory`() API ).
I suspect it is temporary copy used by the above APIs. I need the unicode value and need to secure my data. How can I achieve that?

The code snippet is shared below.

```
CHAR* pszPassword = NULL;
UINT unPlainTextLen  = 0;

// Decrypt the secure data
if( DecryptSecureData( pszPassword, unPlainTextLen))
{
    WCHAR *ptcszPassword_o = new WCHAR[unPlainTextLen + 1];
    ptcszPassword_o[ unPlainTextLen ] = 0;
    size_t unSizeConverted = 0;
    if( 0 == mbstowcs_s( &unSizeConverted, ptcszPassword_o, unPlainTextLen + 1, 
                         reinterpret_cast<CHAR*>( pszPassword ), unPlainTextLen ))
    {   

       // Clear Decrypted o/p buffer
       SecureZeroMemory( pszPassword, unPlainTextLen);
       delete[] pszPassword;

       // Process unicode data ptcszPassword_o

       SecureZeroMemory( ptcszPassword_o, unPlainTextLen  * 2 );
       delete[] pszPassword;
    }              
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code surrounding your calls to the conversion and `SecureZeroMemory`? Preferrably just make it a SSCCE

Comment: If you want to be secure you should be careful to not pass it to dynamically linked functions. Your best bet for real security is probably to just statically link ICU and actually inspect whether the source is copying it somewhere or not.

Comment: Bear in mind that you need exception handling as if something throws and you don't delete your `new`'d pointer then it certainly will be sitting around in memory

Comment: I'm surprised that `mbstowcs_s` creates copies, perhhaps you should investigate further where the copy is coming from.  Make sure you are staticly linking to MSVC runtime of course.

Comment: BTW I would suggest storing the password in the same format that it was entered, i.e. not doing any conversions in the first place!

Answer (score 0):

Considering it's just (multi)byte to wide, a `WCHAR lookup[256]` may be a viable solution. You can init that table using a dummy string passed to `MultiByteToWideChar` - that's no security leak. Downside: this doesn't work for actual multibyte encodings.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution to convert to wide character without a temporary copy.

```
CHAR* pszSecuredData;
// Holds the secured multibyte data in pszSecuredData.

WCHAR* ptcszSecureData = new wchar_t[unSecureDataLength + 1];
swprintf( ptcszSecureData, unSecureDataLength + 1, L"%S", pszSecuredData );
```

Comment: This version will not translate UTF-8 or any other encoding, which is the whole point of `MultiByteToWideChar` or `mbstowcs`